# ASIHTTPRequest simultaneous download of images on tableview takes time

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview, asihttprequest

I have used ASIHTTPRequest framework in my project to handle all network related tasks.

I have custom cell with thumbnail which is coming from web server and there are around 500 images so I have to reuse the cell to handle it. Due reusing of cell when we scroll through tableview we can see images of previous cells which will be replaced by new image.

If network connection is low its worse since it takes lot of time to download the image..so for that time you can see wrong image for particular because reusing cell so I need to find way so that this image replacement shouldn't be visible to user.

I am using ASIDownalod SharedCache method.

EDIT

```
NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"offerCell";

BRZOfferCell *offerCell = (BRZOfferCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

if (offerCell==nil) {

    offerCell = [[[BRZOfferCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier celltype:kDealCellTypeDealsList] autorelease];
}

[offerCell setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_NO_IMAGE]];

//---get the letter in the current section---
//NSString *alphabet = [mDealsIndex objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];

//---get all deals beginning with the letter---
NSString* lSectionIndex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[indexPath section]];

NSMutableArray *deals = [mIndexedOffersDic objectForKey:lSectionIndex];


if ([deals count]>0) {
    //---extract the relevant deal from the deals array object---
    Offer* lOffer = [deals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [offerCell setOffer:lOffer];

    offerCell.accessoryView = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    if (mTableView.dragging == NO && mTableView.decelerating == NO)
    {
        //Function : format image url to _thumb@2x.png and Initiate Image request download 
        //and set  cache policy
        [mListViewHelper InitImageRequest: lOffer.PromoImage indexPath: indexPath];
    }

}

return offerCell;
```

Comment: It would help to see the code for your UITableView delegate methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used ASIDownloadCache methods to solve my problem. Actually there are 2 solutions for this problem

1. Setting your own cache path instead of using SharedCache but i didn't went for this becuase I was already using sharedCache and found another efficient method which will avoid me changing my current implementation
2. In this approach I have used 2 methods from ASIDownloadCache methods(surprisingly ASIHTTPREquest website didn't mention these methods in their brief info)

   2.1 First method `- (BOOL)isCachedDataCurrentForRequest:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request`
        to verify if this particular image url is already cached or not if yes use 2nd method
   2.2 `- (NSData *)cachedResponseDataForURL:(NSURL *)url` to get the cached image so that we can set the image in cellForRowAtIndexPath itself and you will not see image replacing issue due reusability of cell.

Here is the code :

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"offerCell";


BRZOfferCell *offerCell = (BRZOfferCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

if (offerCell==nil) {

    offerCell = [[[BRZOfferCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier celltype:kDealCellTypeDealsList] autorelease];
}

[offerCell setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_NO_IMAGE]];

//---get the letter in the current section---
//NSString *alphabet = [mDealsIndex objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];

//---get all deals beginning with the letter---
NSString* lSectionIndex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[indexPath section]];

NSMutableArray *deals = [mIndexedOffersDic objectForKey:lSectionIndex];


if ([deals count]>0) {
    //---extract the relevant deal from the deals array object---
    Offer* lOffer = [deals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [offerCell setOffer:lOffer];

    offerCell.accessoryView = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    if ([mListViewHelper isCached:lOffer.PromoImage]) { // Is image available in Cache ?

        // Image  is available use image fomr cache directly 
        [offerCell setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[mListViewHelper cacheDataWithNSURL:lOffer.PromoImage]]];
    }
    else{
        //Function : Initiate Image request download and set cache policy

        if (mTableView.dragging == NO && mTableView.decelerating == NO)
            [mListViewHelper InitImageRequest: lOffer.PromoImage indexPath: indexPath];
    }
}

return offerCell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said UITableView reuses cells in order to perform well, so you need to clear the cell before reuse it, or it's going to display the wrong data.

You also should use asynchronous calls, and some delegation to update cells.

I would actually take it a level higher and use NSOperationQueue, that allows you to set the maximum number of concurrent downloads, and canceling requests when leaving page.

What you might want to do is to create Data helpers

```
@protocol BookDataHelperDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) bookDataHelperDidLoadImage:(BookDataHelper *)dataHelper;
@end

@interface BookDataHelper

@property (nonatomic, retian) UIImage *bookCover;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Book *book;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSObject<BookDataHelperDelegate> *delegate;

- (void) fetchImageAsynchronouslyFromWebWithDelegate:(NSObject<BookDataHelperDelegate> *)delegate;

@end
```

This would be how you reload data on your table

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView
    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
       cell = [[[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
       reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    BookDataHelper *dataHelper = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (!dataHelper.bookCover)
    {
         [cell.imageView setImage:nil];
         [dataHelper fetchImageAsynchronouslyFromWebWithDelegate:self];
    } 
    else
    {
         [cell.imageView setImage:dataHelper.bookCover];
    }

    cell.bookTitleLabel.text = dataHelper.book.title;
    return cell;

}

- (void)bookDataHelperDidLoadImage:(BookDataHelper *)datahelper
{
   [tableView reloadDate];
   // here you would either reload the table completely
   // Or you could reload specific cells
}
```

Comment: I have implemented same way with delegate but now...as i scroll it takes a some time to load image on cell.. since i have other text which getting replaced in no time but not happening same with image...

Comment: i think in your code  you are keeping downloaded images into array  am i right ?

Comment: will it not create memory problem as you are storing all those images into array objects..in my case there are 500 images..

Comment: I have found better solution for this in ASIHTTPRequest framework but i think your method will also resolve my problem its just m more worried about memory.. so upvote for suggesting this method..

Comment: downloaded images are stored in dataHelper.bookCover. And for each cell you have a dataHelper object stored in myArray

Comment: yup.. got it..i considered it as one of the approach but i find another approach which is more suitable for me and we don't have to store image in array.

Answer (score 0):

In your tableview cell delegate, when you get a reused or new, cell, clear the image before returning it.  Update with the proper ownloaded image in an asynchronous callback.  You might want to make sure the images are saved or retained somewhere else though if you don't want your app to keep redownloading them.

Comment: I have implemented shared cache with delegate but i think as i m using this delegate it takes time to show the image its not as fast as text...

Answer (score 0):

in ASIHTTPRequest framework  its work on both type Synchronize and ASynchronize so firat tell me which one u use for get image data & also tell me that u send whole 500 image request at time or send as per your cell is loaded

or if you send 500 images request at a time than this on is not right as per the cell requirement send the request fro that cell image other wise its not feasible.